# In GEE, how to solve the problem of the lack of Landsat images in a large area, and the poor image quality after early cloud removal?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat

During Landsat time series analysis for the period of 1990 to 22 (ecological or human applications), in my AOI where the length of lake is ~30 km, the images in Landsat collection 2 was still not optimal for my studies.

To resolve this, I could use a year before and after mosaic? But might result in undesired results for my ecological, human activities studies.
I could also utilize multi-source data fusion adding MODIS in my analysis. Which would be better suited for such analysis. Meanwhile, I would be happy to explore any other way to resolve this problem, but primarily utilizing Landsat collection 2 imagery.

Here is a link to my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5f3d1e2a1c9f403e7782f3151a38767f

Sample script:

```
var year;
var roi = table.geometry();
var startDate = year + '-04-01';
var endDate = year + '-10-31';

function maskL457sr(image) {
  // Bit 0 - Fill
  // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
  // Bit 2 - Unused
  // Bit 3 - Cloud
  // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

  // Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .addBands(thermalBand, null, true)
      .updateMask(qaMask)
      .updateMask(saturationMask);
}

function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bit 0 - Fill
  // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
  // Bit 2 - Cirrus
  // Bit 3 - Cloud
  // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);
 
 
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
 
  
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
      .updateMask(qaMask)
      .updateMask(saturationMask);
}

function processLandsat5(year) {
  var startDate = year + '-04-01';
  var endDate = year + '-10-31';
  var landsat5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterBounds(roi)
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .map(maskL457sr)
      .select(['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B7','ST_B6'], ['SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B7','ST_B10']);
  
  return landsat5;
}

function processLandsat8(year) {
  var startDate = year + '-04-01';
  var endDate = year + '-10-31';
  var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterBounds(roi)
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .map(maskL8sr)
      .select(['SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B7','ST_B10']);
  
  return landsat8;
}

function processLandsat7(year) {
  var startDate = year + '-04-01';
  var endDate = year + '-10-31';
  var landsat7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterBounds(roi)
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .map(maskL457sr)
      .select(['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B7','ST_B6'], ['SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B7','ST_B10']);
  
  return landsat7;
}

var dataset;


for (var year = 1990; year <= 2021; year++) {
    if (year < 2012) {
    
      var landsat5 = processLandsat5(year);
      dataset = landsat5.median().clip(roi);
    } else if (year == 2012) {

      dataset = processLandsat7(year).median().clip(roi);
    } else {

      var landsat8 = processLandsat8(year);
      dataset = landsat8.median().clip(roi);
    }
    var visualization = {
        bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
        min: 0.0,
        max: 0.3,
    };
     
    Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, "True Color (432)"+year);
}
```

[image]